# Apache Rewrite/Permissions (Limiting Post)

Tags: linux, apache

Greetings fellow coders,

I would like to block all post requests on my Apache server except from two pages: index.php, and submit.php. I've followed the example here (https://perishablepress.com/protect-post-requests/) to get the following code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/submit_.php [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index.php [NC] 
    RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
</IfModule>
```

I'm running into an issue however that whenever I try to load index.php or submit.php, I get the following two errors:

```
Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0

( ! ) Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/index.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in Unknown on line 0
```

Did I miss something? Both index.php and submit.php both have a chmod of 640 and work perfectly without those rewrite lines. I was under the impression that the ! would make it only apply to pages other than index and submit.

**UPDATE:**
Here's the code for index.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload</title>
<style type="text/css">
.tinyFont
{
    font-weight:normal;color:#000000;letter-spacing:1pt;word-spacing:2pt;font-size:12px;text-align:center;font-family:arial, helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<br><br>

<form class="CSS_Goes_here" action="submit.php" align="center" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="custEmail">Customer Email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="custEmail" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['custEmail'])){echo $_GET['custEmail'];}?>" style="height:30px; width:300px; font-size: 12pt;" required>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="file" capture="camera" accept="image/*" name="uploaded_file" style="margin-left: 130px;" required>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p class="tinyFont">Accepted File Types: JPG, BMP, PNG, GIF, PDF.</p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" style="height:40px; width:150px; font-size: 18pt; margin-left: 100px;">
</form>
<h2><br></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just a side note: the full stop (`.`) should be backslash escaped in the `RewriteCond`'s pattern, so for example `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/submit_\.php` But as said: that is only a side note, not solving the issue at hand.

Comment: I do not see any connection between those rules you post and the effect you describe. However what does look strange to me is the path mentioned in the error message... That is not an error raised by the apache http server, it is raised by the php engine trying to include a file `/var/www/index.php` and fails. So some script _is_ actually executed. And requires some other script. Please post that scripts code inside the question. Thanks.

Comment: This looks a bit like an issue with the working directory getting changed by your attempts to modify that dynamic configuration file. I could imagine other rewriting rules _not_ getting applied because of your changes.